# Do Steam or Battle.Net Terms of Service restrict the ability to play games remotely via streaming?

Tags: steam, battle.net, legal, steam-in-home-streaming

I find myself frequently moving between two locations, and I'm finding I have to move my PC from one location to another. I've thought about simplifying this, and one way to do this might be to stream my PC to a remote location.

However, would this be against the terms of service of services like steam and battle.net? And if so, would it effect "anti cheat hooks?"

Comment: As we can't ask for recommendations in questions, does anyone have any suggestions for software that could do this? So far I've only come across simulating steam in-home streaming by using Hamachi to make my PCs think they're on the same network.

Comment: We're not really qualified to give legal advice, but I doubt that using a "remote desktop" service like RDC or VNC will break and TOS: you are still a single user, running a single instance of the game on a single machine. *Sharing* your desktop to multiple people at a time would be a different story.

Comment: Strictly speaking, every software is run "remotely". Your PC has to send its video output to a "remote" screen, and needs to read input from a "remote" keyboard and mouse. Legally speaking, it's a different issue, but I doubt you'll get in trouble for gaming remotely.

Comment: you can do this on steam, also maybe teamviewer, but remember it's not going to work well for a lot of games due to the extra ping and/or reduced quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steam officially supports LAN game streaming, and you can extend your LAN by managing to get some sort of VPN system to work.

IANAL, but streaming your video gameplay through a VPN is not conceptually different from streaming it through Twitch -- you're taking the video feed, which is technically a derivative work of the copyrighted videogame, routing it through a third party and then to another client. If anything, Twitch is a little bit iffier since you are actually publishing the derivative work, whereas in your case the stream is for your private use. Still, if you want to play it safe, you should <s>limit yourself to the game's livestreaming rules</s> **ask a lawyer for legal advice.**

Before you try, however, try playing some games over wifi with Steam's in house streaming. I found many games basically unplayable, and Steam basically begs you to connect it over Ethernet. Do your own research before you add 80ms more latency with a VPN and find yourself frustrated even playing [a turn based terminal game](https://crawl.project357.org/).

Comment: Pick the farthest server from you at https://crawl.develz.org/play.htm and try playing through the tutorial.